# Show that $f(x,y)= \|x-y\|_2^2$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, self-learning, intuition

> **Problem**: Show that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=\|x-y\|_2^2$ is differentiable and compute its differential at every point in the domain of $f$
> **Note**: $\| \cdot \|_2$ denotes the euclidian norm $d(x,y)_2 =\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$

One exercise I found in **Zorich Analysis II**. I am however in **general** clueless on how to show that a function is differentiable. Of course there is always the brute force way such as computing the Jacobian-Matrix and discuss its entries, however that might be a little bit difficult with the above mapping since $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, that would be one hell of a matrix to compute.

I found that most people enjoy working with this definition of differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$

> $f(x)=f(x_0)+A(x-x_0)+\|x-x_0\|\alpha (x)$ where $\alpha: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \alpha (x)=0$ and $A$ is a linear function.

I understand that the above is only a slight variation of:

> **Def**: $f$ is at $x_0$ differentiable $\iff \exists A: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n: \displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-A(x-x_0)}{\|x-x_0\|}=0 $

In **C.T. Michaels Analysis II** the author mentions that by the definition nothing is known about the linear mapping $A$, however in most cases $A$ can easily be found by computing the Jacobian-Matrix and then verifying the definition with that Matrix.

I have read a couple of entries on this website where people attempt to show that a function is differentiable or not at some generic point. But to be honest it all seemed a bit like Voodoo-Magic to me.

**Question**: I am not primarily interested in the solution to this exercise but in the thought process one would have to show that $f$ defined as above is differentiable:

- Where do you start?
- Is there something in specific you have to notice about the function beforehand? Like symmetry, roots or anything to start discussing its differential.
- Is it a lot of lucky guessing and in the end succeeding after a lot of failed attempts? Or is there something like a 'most natural attempt' to generally solve such exercises.

Comment: I take $\lVert\cdot \rVert_2$ is the Euclidean norm?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff exactly, pardon me I might should have add that, I will do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note this is the map $(x,y)\mapsto (x-y)\cdot (x-y)$, that is $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot x-2x\cdot y+y\cdot y$. It suffices we show each of the summands is differentiable. But two of the summands are $\lVert \cdot \rVert ^2$; which we know how to differentiate, and the central summand is bilinear, so it is not too hard to obtain their derivative. In fact, we obtain that $$Df(x,y)(a,b)=2x\cdot a-2(x\cdot b+a\cdot y)+2 b\cdot y\\=2x\cdot(a-b)-2y\cdot(a-b)=2(x-y)\cdot (a-b)$$

Note that if $g(x,y)=x\cdot x$, then $Df(x,y)(a,b)=2x\cdot a$ and if $h(x,y)=y\cdot y$ then $Dh(x,y)(a,b)=2y\cdot b$. This is easily proven by say $$g(x+k,y+k)-g(x,y)=2x\cdot h+\lVert h\rVert ^2$$ $$h(x+k,y+k)-h(x,y)=2y\cdot k+\lVert k\rVert ^2$$ and noting $\lVert h\rVert,\lVert k\rVert \leqslant \lVert (h, k)\rVert$.

> *Claim* Let $B:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^p$ bilinear. Then $DB(x,y)(a,b)=B(x,b)+B(a,y)$. More generally, if  $T:\Bbb R^{i_1}\times\cdots \Bbb R^{i_k }\to\Bbb R^p$ multilinear, $$DT(x_1,\ldots,x_k)(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=\sum_{j=1}^k T(x_1,\ldots,a_j,\ldots,x_k)$$

*Proof* I give the proof for the bilinear case, I leave the other proof out.

Indeed, suppose $B:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^p$ is bilinear. Then $$B(x+h,y+k)=B(x,y)+B(x,k)+B(h,y)+B(h,k)$$

Thus $$B(x_0+h,y_0+k)-B(x_0,y_0)=B(x_0,k)+B(h,y_0)+B(h,k)$$

Let $A:\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R  $ be the map that sends $(a,b)$ to $B(x_0,b)+B(a,y_0)$. This is *linear*, and the above gives  $$B(x_0+h,y_0+k)-B(x_0,y_0)=A(h,k)+B(h,k)$$

It suffices we show that $B(h,k)$ os $o(\lVert h,k\rVert)$. Let $e_i,e_j$ be the canonical bases for $\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m$. If $h=(h_1,\ldots,h_n),k=(k_1,\ldots,k_m)$ then $$B(h,k)=\sum_{i,j} h_ik_j B(e_i,e_j)$$ and $|h_j|,|k_i|\leqslant \lVert h,k\rVert$, so if $C=\sum_{i,j}\lVert B(e_i,e_j)\rVert $ (a constant depending only on $B$ and the basis of choice)

$$\lVert B(h,k)\lVert\leqslant C\lVert h,k\rVert^2$$

Comment: Thanks @PedroTamaroff, I appreciate it. So far in class I have only seen what a bilinear form is to discuss the scalar product, we did not differentiate it yet or discuss its derivative (might be a topic of vector analysis which I have next term)

Comment: @Spaced I will add something on how to differentiate a bilinear form.

Comment: hmm ... how do you define $||h, k||$ ??

Comment: @SantoshLinkha It is the usual Euclidean norm of $(h,k)\in \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$.

Comment: umm ... is it $||h||_2 ||k||_2$ ?? or $|\sum_{i, j}h_ik_l|$ ?? or something like that. First I have derivative defined at two points, and now I have norm defined at two points.

Comment: Neither, it is the squateroot of $||h||_2^2+||v||_2^2$

Answer (score 1):

When solving this kind of problems, your eyes are often more important than your memory. I mean: look at the function and try to collect as much information as you can. For instance, your function is sum of squares, and this may be really helpful. 
Then you can try to apply the criterion of the directional derivative: if $$L=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{f(x+\varepsilon h_1,y+\varepsilon h_2)-f(x,y)}{\varepsilon}$$ exists, is linear in $h_1$ and $h_2$, and is continuous in $(x,y)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$ (and $L=Df(x,y)(h_1,h_2)$. Sometimes this is easier to apply than the mere definition of derivative in several variables.

But do not forget that intructors tend to construct functions for which the only tool is the direct analysis of $f(x+u,y+v)-f(x,y)$.

Comment: I have done the following calculations: $f(x+ \epsilon h_1, y + \epsilon h_2)= \sum((x-y)+\epsilon(h_1-h_2))^2 = \sum (x-y)^2+ 2 \sum ((x-y)\epsilon(h_1-h_2))+ \sum(\epsilon(h_1-h_2))^2$ such that $f(x+ \epsilon h_1, y+ \epsilon h_2) - f(x,y)= 2 \sum (x-y) \epsilon (h_1-h_2) + n ( \epsilon (h_1-h_2))^2$. Division by $\epsilon$ and taking the limit will have me left with $ 2 \sum (x-y)(h_1-h_2)= 2 ||x-y||(h_1-h_2)$ Is that what you meant @Siminore?

Comment: You made a mistake in the last identity. By the way, the derivative along $(h_1,h_2)$ must be $2 \langle x-y,h_1-h_2 \rangle$.

Comment: I see it now thank you, of course, there is no euclidian norm present anymore at $2 \sum (x-y)(h_1-h_2)=2<x-y,h_1-h_2>$

Comment: pardon me to tag you once again @Siminore, but I have just read a few pathologic examples about if the directional derivatives exists in all directions, then the function does not have to be differentiable. Does the linearity of $h_1$ and $h_2$ and the continuity contribute to the fact that the exists of the directional derivative in all directions implies total differentiation?

Comment: Yes, of course. The directional derivative may exists but it may not be linear in the increment. In this case the function can't be differentiable (since the derivative must be a liner operator).